# moved websites to a different server

Tags: codeigniter, server-migration

I have moved a website that uses ExpressionEngine to a different server, however all the images appear to be missing and if I go to update something it says the path is invalid.

I just spotted another error as I was going through the migration documentation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone advise on how do I fix this, I am new to ExpressionEngine and CodeIgniter

Answer (score 2):

An EE configuration needs to know both the URL of the site and the local path to the webroot folder within the server you are using to operate.

If you have changed servers then it is likely that the local path to the webroot folder will have changed, and as a result EE operations that rely on accessing files stored below that webroot folder (such as images) will fail until you provide the correct path.

There are good instructions on how to move an EE2 installation from one server to another [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/operations/moving.html).

HTH

Comment: I just installed the server test wizard on both old and new servers to see what is different. The new server where I moved my website to doesnt have File Information (fileinfo), could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't have access to a live EE2 site right now, but you might also want to check the configuration of the file upload directories themselves, which also have specific paths defined - these too need to be updated.  You can read about these in this documentation - https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html

Comment: Thank you, the issue was as you said. I have asked my hosting provider to migrate the account from the old to new server and that solved everything

Answer (score 0):

webroot folder

The answer above is probabaly right

My image folder is know, yet I would not have the foggiest idea what the webroot folder is.

Maybe the server can show you.  Also if you use  transmit or another upload device to upload your files, that has to be configured with the webroot folder

Comment: The webroot folder is simply the one that is where the files that appear 'in the root directory of your website' live - so if to access your website you normally open a domain `https://domain.com/index.html` - the folder that the file 'index.html' is in is the one referred to as the webroot.  ExpressionEngine will access the files within your website directly on the server you are running your site on as part of the work it does to show your site to visitors, but it needs to know what the path to that webroot folder is - hence the need to specify the path as part of EE configuration.  HTH!